# Fix blink in Fragments during addSharedElement() transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment-transitions

I use the next code in Fragment A:

```
fragmentManager!!
            .beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(viewHolder.characterImage, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(viewHolder.characterImage))
            .addToBackStack(TAG)
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContent, CharacterFragment.newInstance(url, viewHolder.characterName.text.toString()))
            .commit()
```

And next code in Fragment B:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        sharedElementEnterTransition = android.transition.TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    }
```

And during first transition, I have blink, during next transitions everything is fine. I saw the fix for Activity transition but it is not my case. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the problem is in Glide with Picasso everything works fine.